# How to record the timestamp into a database table when the broswer or tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, php

First I would like to thank everyone who read my post and tried to help or at least read my post :)
My question is, is there a way to record the timestamp of when the browser or tab being closed ?
I read that we can use session in php to know when the session has expired but is there a way to know when it was closed ? or in javascript ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Comment: I did not understand how the time has been recorded, i need to record the time to a table in the database. How can i do that ? I changed the question to what i really need